# When I open the Music D/L app, it quits immediately

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

I have an iPad mini, and I have this app called Music D/L. So, a few months ago, I decided to download a song and when I went into the app, it had a black screen for a split second, and it just crashed.

In the comments please don't say "delete the app and download it again, everything will be fine!". Trust me, it won't :(. This music app was taken down on the App Store, so I can't get it again if I delete it. All of my songs are on this app and I don't want to delete the app and get a new music downloader because:

1. There isn't that many good ones out there.
2. I won't be able to remember all of the music I downloaded.

Please tell me what to do ASAP!

P.S. Yes, I tried resetting my iPad and turning it off and all that stuff, I tried everything!

Comment: Oh and by the way, this 'crashing' had been happening on a few other apps, too. My computer is broken, so no answers with computers please and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I googled a bit and you're not the only one with this problem. It could be that Apple has decided that this app is a bad app. That would explain why it's not available in the App Store anymore and why it won't start anymore: Apple can do that (I think it has to do with the certificate of the developer).

Another possibility would be that you upgraded to a newer version of iOS and that the app is not compatible with the newer version. And for some reason, the developer is no longer supporting the app.

Either way, I don't think it is possible to retrieve your songs. Please don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try not to shoot the messenger. I'll try to get a new app. I also has a look on Google, and it said that it could be because of little storage. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: The second suggestion is far more likely than the first. The app most likely needs to be upgraded to work with the current version of iOS. But if the app is gone off the App store, then that's never going to happen. @op is unfortunately S.O.L. here.